# How can I implement a new handle for a Moose type trait?

Tags: perl, moose

Lets's say I wanted to add `say` functionality to `String` *( note: this is a more simple example than reality )*. So I could have

```
has foo => (
   isa => 'Str',
   traits => [ 'String' ],
   handles => {
     say_foo => 'say',
   }
);
```

which I then of course would be able to use to do.

```
$self->foo( 'bar' );

$self->say_foo;
```

which would print literally

```
'bar\n'
```

I imagine the subroutine would be something like this

```
sub _say_attr {
   my ( $self, $attr ) = @_;
   say $attr;
}
```

Can anyone help me fill in the gaps on how I might actually implement this? I don't really see much in the way of documentation on how to write your own `handles`.

I don't really need to know how to modify the `String` traits. So much as I want to be able to have a generic handler, where I don't need to know the name of the current attribute in order to make it work.

```
has foo => (
    isa => 'Str',
    traits => [ 'PrintString' ],
     handles => {
         say_foo => 'say',
     }
);
has bar => (
    isa => 'Str',
    traits => [ 'PrintString' ],
     handles => {
         say_bar => 'say',
     }
);
```

so `say` here is probably an identifier for a function which does not need a hardcoded name of an attribute which is calling it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to add `say` to `String`, or would you be content with adding `say_foo` to `foo`?

The latter is easy:

```
has foo => (
   isa => 'Str',
   traits => [ 'String' ],
   handles => {
     say_foo => sub { say $_[0]->foo; },
   }
);
```

If you wanted to a more general solution, You should look at [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::String](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aAttribute%3a%3aNative%3a%3aTrait%3a%3aString) and copy/wrap/subclass it rather than trying to change it.

Comment: not so much that I need to say... modify string... but that I don't want to have to know the name of the attribute so I can generically apply this behavior to multiple attributes.

Comment: @xenotarracide, Then I suggest you take a peek at an existing trait and emulate what it does. I you still have problem then, ask a more specific question.